# Twitter Bootstrap: inline selects not aligning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/aGy2P/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select class="span6" name="range-from:price" id="price_from">
                                <option value="">Min Price</option>                                 
                                <option value="2000">$2K</option>
                                <option value="4000">$4K</option>
                                <option value="6000">$6K</option>
                                <option value="8000">$8K</option>
                                <option value="10000">$10K</option>
                                <option value="15000">$15K</option>
                                <option value="20000">$20K</option>
                                <option value="25000">$25K</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="span6 pull-right" name="range-to:price" id="price_to">
                                <option value="">Max Price</option>
                                    <option value="2000">$2K</option>
                                <option value="4000">$4K</option>
                                <option value="6000">$6K</option>
                                <option value="8000">$8K</option>
                                <option value="10000">$10K</option>
                                <option value="15000">$15K</option>
                                <option value="20000">$20K</option>
                                <option value="500000">$25K+</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select class="span6" name="range-from:model_year" id="model_year_from">
                                <option value="">Min Year</option>                                  
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="span6 pull-right" name="range-to:model_year" id="model_year_to">
                                <option value="">Max Year</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>             
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
        </div>
        <div class="span2">         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you make the result pane wide enough, you'll see the select fields try to go in an inline layout. I'm having a bit of problem with this, but it's not clearly seen in JSFiddle.

My screen shot

[image: Chrome] <-- from Chrome, aligns correctly

However, in FF and IE, the "Max Year" select is not horizontally aligned with "Min Year"; instead, it's much lower, like this:

[image] <-- from FF

Initially, I thought it may have something to do with the contents of "Min Year" or "Max Year", so I started tweaking them. But nothing fixed it. When I deleted the node for "Min Price" and "Max Price", then "Min Year" and "Max Year" were suddenly OK.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: People ask for the code in your question so that if your fiddle link goes dead, your question won't be useless to future visitors.

Comment: when/how does a jsfiddle link go dead

Comment: @albert when jsfiddle goes dead? happened to link shorteners before..

Comment: well jsfiddle isn't a link shortener, but i see your point.

Answer (score 2):

Well the issue is the following:

```
    <div class="span2">
    ...other code
        <div class="span6">
             your dropdown    
        </div>
     ...other code
    </div>
```

You are trying to put a span6 inside a span2 container, which just isn't big enough to contain that.

You need to change the span2 to a span12 like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/3N754/

Or note that if you want to put two span6 inside a span 2 you need to have more `<div class='row-fluid'>`

E.g.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    Fluid 12
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        Fluid 6
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That means the `.row-fluid` contains a `.span12`, `.span8`, `.span2` = 20. The total must be 12 only. The `.span2` represents my left sidebar.

Comment: You need to either change the width of the span they are in or change the span class on the selects to be less or equal to the span class they are within.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Apparently this is not the problem: `If you make the result pane wide enough, you'll see the select fields try to go in an inline layout.` OP knows about the fact the left sidebar is too small, but it seems (to what I understand) that's not that which is causing the glitch on FF.

Comment: I disagree that the sidebar is too small. The sidebar is `.span2`, which is what I want. Inside that `.span2`, I have two `.span6`. These are percentage values. `.span6` is 48.717948717948715% of its container (and that container being a `.span2`, which is 14.52991452991453% of its container).

Comment: Have a look at : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem and check out the nesting title and see if you think that putting two span6 inside a 2 makes sense.

Comment: Their example has a `.span6` containing a `.row-fluid` containing two `.span6`. In any case, there is a separate section for discussing the widths of the form field: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms (see the section for "Grid Sizing").

Comment: But you don't have a second row-fluid around your spans. If you are going to have a two span6 inside a span2 you need row-fluid around the two span6. Check my updated answer regarding that.

Comment: If I had two `div.span6`, then I would agree that I need another `div.row-fluid` to contain them. However, I do not have two `div.span6`. Instead, I have two `select.span6`. There isn't a requirement for the form fields to be inside a div container. Plus, the first pair looks just fine. It's the subsequent pairs that have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I also believe the problem is white spaces between elements ( and there is one between the second pair of `select` tags ). They do really matter in `inline` and `inline-block` elements as they force the elements to wrap like words do when hey exceed their containers width. Two simple solutions are, either remove the spaces between elements, or add a `white-space:nowrap;` rule on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

First, you put a Jsfiddle that doesn't reproduce your problem (and that has another problem: the widtch is too small), I don't get the point of that.

Anyway, you put span6 on your select: `<select class="span6"`

But you didn't put them in a `<div class="row-fluid"></div>`.

Comment: The form fields also support a `.span*`, which is different from the `div.span*` in `div.row` and `div.row-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is often caused by space between elements.

Because if one element occupies 50% and the second 50% too, a simple space between them makes them bigger than 100%.

Usually you can:

- remove spaces / breakline between your elements (in this case, your selects)
- set the fontsize to 0 to the container so that spaces "don't occupy spaces". :)

This might not be the solution to your particular case but maybe for others with the same kind of problem.

Let me know.

EDIT:

please look at this modified fiddle: I am using chrome on MacOs and we know results might be different but when I tried your example, every select was on a different line.

In the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3nJYY/1/, I have removed the spaces /breakline between the selects of the first group. Now they are displayed on the same line (what you were looking for), while the selects in the second group are placed on different lines.

here is the important part, note that I've removed any space or breakline between the closing select and the second one:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="span6" name="range-from:price" id="price_from">
            ...
        </select><select class="span6 pull-right" name="range-to:price" id="price_to">
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Amida, the answer is too general. Can you be more specific with my situation?

Comment: i have completed my answer

Comment: I looked at my mark up to check for spaces between the tags. There aren't any. Also, white spaces between tags are generally ignored in HTML (except in `pre` and `code`). So, I'm not convinced of your answer. Also, did you check your answer in IE or FF?

Comment: A breakline will often result in creating a space between elements. That's why in bootstrap they set the font size to zero in some cases. For example for the add-on in input forms.

Comment: If your actual code is like in the fiddle you have provided, then yes you have spaces/tabs/breakline and removing them solved the problem on my side in chrome/FF in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap-combined.min.css file you are including includes Bootstrap Responsive. The compiled responsive styles have very precise width percentages for .span* elements. After playing around with the code and developer tools in Chrome, I was able to see that different browser widths indeed produced different results.

Ex. 1: browser width at least 1200px

[image: 1200+px viewport]

Ex. 2: browser width between 786 and 969px

[image: 768-969px viewport]

It seems these widths were made for divs without taking into consideration excess width from select boxes.

A css ninja may have a better solution than this. But setting your select width slightly smaller should solve the problem without making the form look too bad.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .row-fluid select.span6 {
    width: 48%;
  }
</style>
```

48.0% seemed good to me for select.span6, though since these are native select boxes, width may vary between operating systems. (I am using OSX.) Use different values above and see what works best for all possible browser widths.

Furthermore, if you don't need responsive capabilities (i.e. if you don't care about your site being mobile-optimized), include only the regular bootstrap css. Your site will then be displayed one way for all viewports and you won't have to worry about how it looks on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that when you apply the .span6 style to a select, the browser will apply the 48,.... percentage size, but then will add some extra-length to render the  component, making it too long to fit, and therefore slide under the other one.

As a workaround, I would propose to wrap the select in a div, and apply the .span6 class to the div instead so that you are sure that the browser renders the proper length. Then you would have to add give a width of 100% to your select to fit in your div

http://jsfiddle.net/SkMZ5/2/

example :

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="span6">
        <select style="width:100%" name="range-from:model_year" id="model_year_from">
            <option value="">Min Year</option>              
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="span6 pull-right">
        <select style="width:100%" name="range-to:model_year" id="model_year_to">
            <option value="">Max Year</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```